# Airbrake throws error one of the patterns in Airbrake::Filters::KeysBlacklist is invalid when using custom proc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, airbrake

In our application we want to filter certain parameters differently depending on their usage... for example passwords should always be filtered entirely, but for email and name we want to retain parts of the value for debugging and support.

To do this, we've used a custom proc to format them:

`1_filter_parameter_logging.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [
  :password
]

Rails.application.config.filter_parameters << proc do |param_name, value|
  if %w[email name].include?(param_name)
    if param_name.to_s == 'email'
      value.gsub!(/(?<=^.{2}).*?(?=@)/, '*') # test partial filter
    else
      value.replace('[FILTERED_CUSTOM]') # test custom filter
    end
  end
end
```

Then in `2_airbrake.rb` we use these settings as so:

```
c.blacklist_keys = Rails.application.config.filter_parameters
```

To test this theory, we deliberately throw an exception in our app with this example controller action:

```
class ExampleController
  def show
    raise StandardError, 'Testing Filter Parameter Logging'
  end
end
```

And then make a simple request to that endpoint:

```
http://localhost:3000/example?name=cameron&email=cameron@test.com&password=test
```

In our logs we see the following:

```
Processing by ExampleController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"name"=>"[FILTERED_CUSTOM]", "email"=>"ca*@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

And then an error from Airbake:

```
**Airbrake: one of the patterns in Airbrake::Filters::KeysBlacklist is invalid. Known patterns: [:password, nil]
```

And if we look at the error in Airbrake we see that it hasn't filtered them:

```
{
  "action" => "show",
  "controller" => "example",
  "email" => "cameron@test.com",
  "name" => "cameron",
  "password" => "[Filtered]"
}
```

Why is Airbrake throwing that error, seems Rails is able to filter those parameters using that proc based on those logs, but then Airbrake fails to filter them and allows them through.

Airbrake doesn't explain exactly what's invalid with the pattern... just that it doesn't see it as valid, which isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The param filtering offered by [Rails](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/ParameterFilter.html) is different than [Airbrake](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby#blocklist_keys).

Rails allows for complex param filtering.  You can define a `proc` that takes in the parameter `key` and `value` as arguments and returns the filtered value.  The execution of the `proc` happens [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7-0-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/parameter_filter.rb#L135) in `ActiveSupport::ParameterFilter#value_for_key`.

Airbrake is more limited.  It can only filter parameter names by comparing them against a [String, Symbol, or Regexp](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby/blob/v6.2.1/lib/airbrake-ruby/filters/keys_filter.rb#L19).  The [documentation](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby#blocklist_keys) indicates that you can define a `proc` but it only gets executed once on the first notification and:

> The Proc *must* return an Array consisting only of the elements, which are considered to be valid for this option.

The `proc` is executed [here](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby/blob/v6.2.1/lib/airbrake-ruby/filters/keys_filter.rb#L131).  It is called without any arguments.  If your example `proc` is called without arguments it returns `nil`.  Since this doesn't match a String, Symbol, or Regexp an exception is raised [here](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby/blob/v6.2.1/lib/airbrake-ruby/filters/keys_filter.rb#L143).

Airbrake uses a [`should_filter?`](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby/blob/v6.2.1/lib/airbrake-ruby/filters/keys_blocklist.rb#L38) method that takes just the param `key`.  If that method returns `true` the [`"[Filtered]"`](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby/blob/v6.2.1/lib/airbrake-ruby/filters/keys_filter.rb#L15) string replaces the value.  This existing structure isn't easy to quickly override to get the behavior you want.  But you could try to completely override the [`Airbrake::Filters::KeysBlocklist`](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby/blob/v6.2.1/lib/airbrake-ruby/filters/keys_blocklist.rb) class and [`Airbrake::Filters::KeysFilter`](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby/blob/v6.2.1/lib/airbrake-ruby/filters/keys_filter.rb) module.

Note that the info here and all the links are for the current version of `airbrake-ruby`.  [`blacklist_keys` was replaced by `blocklist_keys` several years ago.](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v4150-june-17-2020)  And classes like `KeysBlacklist` were replaced by `KeysBlocklist`.  But these were just naming changes and functionality has remained relatively the same over time.

---

Rather than override the standard Airbrake param filtering, you're probably better off trying to [add a custom filter](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby#airbrakeadd_filter).  Here's an example of what you could try to put into an initializer in your app:

```rb
Airbrake.add_filter do |notice|
  notice[:params].each do |key, value|
    if key == :email
      value.gsub!(/(?<=^.{2}).*?(?=@)/, '*')  # test partial filter
    elsif key == :name
      value.replace('[FILTERED_CUSTOM]')  # test custom filter
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's not ideal that Airbrake doesn't support the same as Rails itself... I'm starting to think perhaps we should move away from Airbrake if it doesn't support this out of the box as we want to avoid monkey patching.

Comment: Unless the monkey patch to make this work with Airbrake isn't as big as I'm thinking?

Comment: I think you may want to try adding an Airbrake filter instead.  I've linked to the docs and added an example of the kind of code you could put in your filter.

Comment: Thanks. That looks to work. I added `notice[:context][:user]` as well. The last bit is that Airbrake records the URL requested and does its own manual filtering here: https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby/blob/v6.2.1/lib/airbrake-ruby/filters/keys_filter.rb#L122 so looks like I'll need to replicate that to filter: `notice[:context][:url]` as well.

Comment: Yeah parsing the URL and then doing the same filtering works. It's a bit messy, but works!

Comment: Marked your answer as accepted and awarded the bounty as well. Thanks!